# Getting full path from WIN32_FIND_DATA

Tags: c++, performance, wchar

I need help with the getting the full path from WIN32_FIND_DATA
my code:

```
WIN32_FIND_DATA FindData;
HANDLE hFind;

hFind = FindFirstFile(L"../art/*.dds", &FindData );

if( hFind == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE )
{
    PrintCharS("Error searching directory");
    return;
}

do
{

    char ch[260];
    char DefChar = ' ';
    WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP, 0, FindData.cFileName, -1, ch, 260, &DefChar, NULL);

    string ss(ch);

    if (ch != "invalid.dds")
    {

        LoadFile( / Need WCHAR* that points to file \ );

    }

}
while( FindNextFile(hFind, &FindData) > 0 );
```

I have literally spend ALL day trying to figure this out.
But I cant get the path (../art/*.dds) plus the filename
also how can I check subfolders? or does it do that already?

Current Code:

```
WIN32_FIND_DATA FindData;
HANDLE hFind;

hFind = FindFirstFile(L"../art/*.dds", &FindData );

if( hFind == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE )
{
    PrintCharS("Error searching directory");
    return;
}

do
{

    char ch[260];
    char DefChar = ' ';
    WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP, 0, FindData.cFileName, -1, ch, 260, &DefChar, NULL);

    string ss(ch);

    // Just incase they're needed
    DWORD  retval=0;
    BOOL   success; 
    TCHAR  buffer[4096]=TEXT(""); 
    TCHAR  buf[4096]=TEXT(""); 
    TCHAR** lppPart={NULL};

    LPSTR buffeer = "";
    LPSTR* lpppPart = NULL;

    retval = GetFullPathNameA(ch, 4096, buffeer, lpppPart);

    if (retval == 0)
    {
        std::exit(1);
    }
    else
    {

        LoadFile( / Expected WCHAR* \ );

    }

}
while( FindNextFile(hFind, &FindData) > 0 );
```

Answer (score 1):

You know the directory you scanned, and the item within that directory that was found.  Append them to get a filename qualified to the same extent as the original search: `../art/something.dds`.  Assuming the current directory has not changed, that should work if fed down to any primitive `OpenFile` call.  But if you really need a fully qualified file name, call [`GetFullPathName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364963%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with that partial name.

P.S.

```
char ch[260];
⋮
if (ch != "invalid.dds")
```

is not going to work.  You are comparing addresses, so it will **always test false** and has nothing to do with the *content* of `ch`.

Comment: I'm completey dumb and tired of working with this but really need it working, I need an example of how to do it. I've tried the GetFullPathName function but doesnt seem to get me anywhere, except for the very first letter of the path.

Comment: @SpecialLUANewbie very first letter:  Sounds like you are getting Unicode (UTF-16) out but treating it as ANSI (8-bit) so you see, e.g. { 64, 0, 65, 0, ...} instead of `L"AB..."`  Avoid the macros and UNICODE #define, and write `GetFullPathNameW` (—*W*) to be clear and get type checking in the case where that setting is inconsistent.

Comment: If you pass in the result of WideCharToMultiByte, it will not work with the unqualified GetFullPathName as I see your context is the -W forms are used.  Pass ch to GetFullPathNameA, or pass the original to GetFullPathNameW.

Comment: @SpecialLUANewbie re *“completey dumb and tired of working with this but really need it working”*  I've been there.  If it's still not working after you have a break and review the latest, post your current code example and I will look at it next time I'm here.  (and please mark the Answer as correct)